Could not connect with Redis Sential by Lettuce in JAVA Spring Boot
I am attempting to connect with Redis Sentinel in JAVA Spring Boot using lettuce. But I am getting error NOAUTH Authentication required.
exception message :: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH Authentication required.

But I am passing password correctly. When I test with Standalone redis connection, it is working. Below is the code for standalone connection.
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration rs = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("redis-host.svc.cluster.local", 6379);
        rs.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("original_password"));
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(rs);
        
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .disableCachingNullValues();
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(lettuceConnectionFactory).cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

Below is the code for connecting to Redis sentinel
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {

        String pwd = "original_password";
        
        RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfiguration = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master("master");                                                           
        sentinelConfiguration.sentinel("redis-host.svc.cluster.local", 26379);
        sentinelConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(pwd));
        
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfiguration);
        
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .disableCachingNullValues();
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(lettuceConnectionFactory).cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

I could connect with same redis sentinel with Node.js properly. Below is the code for Node.js connecting to Redis sentinel correctly.
const Redis = require('ioredis');
 
const redisClient = new Redis({
    sentinels: [
        {
            host: "redis-host.svc.cluster.local",
            port: 26379
        },
    ],
    password: 'original_password',
    sentinelPassword: 'original_password',
    name: 'master',
});
 
 
(async function() {
    await redisClient.set('key', 'value');
    const value = await redisClient.get('key');
    console.log(value);
})();

In node.js (io-redis), it seems like we have to pass both password and sentinelPassword to connect with Redis sentinel. Excluding any of those will result in same error which I am getting for JAVA.
But in java (luttece), I could not see any function to set the password, it only has option to set sentinelPassword password.
Kindly help to resolve this issue.

This class has setters for both passwords:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisSentinelConfiguration.html

Thanks for the documentation. But I could not see the setter function inside RedisSentinelConfiguration class. I am using 3.2.5 version of spring-boot-starter-data-redis package.

This is the class I am referring to org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisSentinelConfiguration;

I can see it... Are you sure you use RedisSentinelConfiguration and not RedisStandaloneConfiguration?

Thanks for your suggestion. I use RedisSentinelConfiguration only but I have used different redis package called spring-boot-starter-data-redis which has no function to pass sentinelPassword. Now I changed to spring-data-redis and I am able to pass the sentinel password sucessfully.

I was initially using spring-boot-starter-data-redis dependency to connect to redis sentinel. But it does not have any function to pass SentinelPassword, so hence redis throws Authentication required error.
Now I changed my redis package to spring-data-redis which has function to pass sentinelPassword and I am able to connect successfully.
